# Tomcat 7 SSL Failed

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I use Tomcat 7 and will enable the SSL Connector.
Actuall i have edit this solution to the `server.xml` file:

```xml
<Connector clientAuth="true"
           port="8443"
           minSpareThreads="5"
           maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="true"
           disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100"
           maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https"
           secure="true"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/server.jks"
           keystoreType="JKS"
           keystorePass="password"
           truststoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/server.jks"
           truststoreType="JKS"
           truststorePass="password"
           SSLVerifyClient="require"
           SSLEngine="on"
           SSLVerifyDepth="2"
           sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

But i get this exception by startup the server.

> Connector attribute SSLCertificateFile
> must be defined when using SSL with
> APR.
> Failed to initialize connector
> [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]

I use a self created Keystore.
Has anybody a good and easy Tutorial or a good idea?

Thanks

P.S. I post my actuall `server.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container", 
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">
  
    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" 
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->
    
    
    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->           
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the 
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
         
<!--
    <Connector  port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
                maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
 -->
 
 <Connector
   clientAuth="true" port="8443" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="75"
   enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
   acceptCount="100" maxThreads="200"
   scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
   keystoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/server.jks"
   keystoreType="JKS" keystorePass="password"
   truststoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/server.jks"
   truststoreType="JKS" truststorePass="password"
   SSLVerifyClient="require" SSLEngine="on" SSLVerifyDepth="2" sslProtocol="TLS"
/>
 
    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">         
    --> 
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->        

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false"/>

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 26):

comment out this line:

```xml
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
```

Comment: Since all I need to do is test on a Windows box this was a great temporary workaround.

Comment: that works for me too. but can u explain what AprLifecycleListener is for?

Comment: It's for the Apache native runtime, a binary you have to compile from source.

Answer (score 22):

You can not use a keystore if you are using the APR connector. It requires the same certificate formats as used by Apache.

EDIT: if you are running either Debian or Ubuntu on Linux you can use the `ssl-cert` package to generate a self-signed cert that would work with the APR connector as documented at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File (scroll down to the APR section).

EDIT: Try this as your `server.xml` file. I removed some of the comments and commented out the APR listener. Your keystore should work now.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <!-- <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" /> -->
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container", 
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" 
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->           
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the 
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->

<!--
    <Connector  port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
                maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
 -->

 <Connector
   clientAuth="true" port="8443" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="75"
   enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
   acceptCount="100" maxThreads="200"
   scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
   keystoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/server.jks"
   keystoreType="JKS" keystorePass="password"
   truststoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/server.jks"
   truststoreType="JKS" truststorePass="password"
   SSLVerifyClient="require" SSLEngine="on" SSLVerifyDepth="2" sslProtocol="TLS"
/>

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">         
    --> 
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->        

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false"/>

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: can i create a SSL connection without a Keystore or can i implement a SSL Connection with my keystore? I would like run a WebService on my Tomcat with a SSL Transportlayer.

Comment: You need a certificate to create an SSL connection: you can either use a keystore if you are NOT using the APR connector, or you MUST use the OpenSSL format certificate files if you are using the APR connector. Change your `server.xml` file and remove the APR listener you have configured and you will be able to use your existing keystore.

Comment: Can you make a example for the server.xml? I dont know how i implement this.

Comment: Post your `server.xml` file and I'll edit my answer to modify it.

Comment: my first question is edit and contains now the server.xml file. thanks

Comment: I use the new server.xml and get a new browser error.
It is a bad certificate error. I use a self signed keystore. Is this the problem?

Comment: Ok, i change in the server.xml clientAuth="true" to false and it´s run in firefox and IE.

Answer (score 2):

8443 port in Tomcat is by default used for SSL connection.

I suggest you see tomcat documentation for SSL:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

There is one more link that I found which could resolve your issue in no time:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes
This is an amazing article. Please go through to resolve the issue.
Hope this helps !

Answer (score 2):

## Disable Auto-Switching

There's a bit of a mean automatic mechanism at work here. I recommend you disable that and EXPLICTLY select your desired connector. Details below.

## Details

You have your connector configured like so:

```xml
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ...
```

The important parameter here is the `protocol` part. The [Tomcat 7 documentation says this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html): (line breaks mine)

> `protocol`
>
> Sets the protocol to handle incoming traffic.
>
> The default value is `HTTP/1.1` which uses an auto-switching mechanism to select either a blocking Java based connector or an APR/native based connector.
>
> If the `PATH` (Windows) or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (on most unix systems) environment variables contain the Tomcat native library, the APR/native connector will be used.
>
> If the native library cannot be found, the blocking Java based connector will be used. Note that the APR/native connector has different settings for HTTPS than the Java connectors.
>
> [...]

So it seems that auto-switching is being used and it doesn't work. And the reason is give in the final paragraph above: we're auto-switching and end up with the "APR" connector.

So then this happens:

1. APR connector has mandatory parameter called `SSLCertificateFile`.
2. We have NOT supplied that parameter inside server.xml.
3. Tomcat complains about that missing parameter.

## Options

So in order to fix this you have several options:

- Turn auto-switching off replace the "HTTP/1.1" text by your desired connector.
- Leave auto-switching on and fix it. By adding the required parameter to server.xml.
- Leave auto-switching on and break it on purpose. By simply deleting "tomcat\bin\tcnative-1.dll". This will trigger the section mentioned above after *If the native library cannot be found*. This is a bit of a dirty solution. And I'm mentioning this here not because I think this is a great idea. But because I happened to find that this had been done on one of our Development Tomcat machines.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to implement SSL on TOMCAT

> (APR implementation of SSL and JSSE implementation of SSL)

The difference is that the JDK is using it's own SSL implementation, while the APR it's using what's installed on the computer, i.e. OpenSSL in most cases.

## First way (jSSE) using java

1. Creating a Keystore file

   (windows-os) in comand prompet cmd [cd $JAVA_HOME/bin]

   ```
   keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
   ```
2. (Configuring Tomcat's SSL Connectors) in (..\Tomcat 8.0\conf\server.xml)

```html
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
 scheme="https" URIEncoding="UTF-8"sslProtocol="TLS"keystorePass="yourPassword"
keystoreFile="locationofkeystorefile" keyAlias="youralias" clientAuth="false" />
```

## Second way (ARP) using openssl

1. Creating a Keystore file using Java
2. (Configuring Tomcat's SSL Connectors) in (..\Tomcat 8.0\conf\server.xml)

```html
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on"  />

<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
port="8443" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
SSLCertificateFile="/tmp/monitoringPortalCert.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile="/tmp/monitoringPortalKey.pem"
SSLPassword="hide"/>
```

## Useful URLs:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html