# tomcat restart from command line differs from restart from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, tomcat7, war

**How does it differ restarting tomcat from command line and from IntelliJ IDEA?**

I thought non. But I found out that when **restarting from command line** (/path/to/Tomcat/bin/restart.sh) and then requesting web app I get java.io.FileNotFoundException in logs (catalina.out).

When I immediately **restart tomcat from a built-in terminal in IntelliJ IDEA** (same script: /path/to/Tomcat/bin/restart.sh) and then requesting web app I get expected result.

Things which I have tried:

1) Initially I thought that this has something to do with my WAR file structure, but it doesn't.

2) I got rid of all references (context container pointing to project folder when developing) in server.xml.

3) Then I read logs and there were some leak warnings, I got rid of them by properly closing streams.

4) I added tomcat-native library.

5) same problem as here and resolved... https://stackoverflow.com/a/17476283/1380304

Same result after each try. IDEA's restart working, cmd line's not. Before try #3 I noticed difference in logs (in catalina.out) after restarting from command line and from IDEA. When using IDEA it seamed, that it did run some additional shutdown commands. Now I got the same logs after both restarts:

calalina.out:

```
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 760 ms
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/test.war
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/test.war has finished in 1,055 ms
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/docs
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/docs has finished in 56 ms
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/examples
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/examples has finished in 264 ms
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/host-manager
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/host-manager has finished in 51 ms
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/manager
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/manager has finished in 49 ms
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/ROOT
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/ROOT has finished in 50 ms
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 13, 2014 3:42:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1593 ms
```

server.xml (other configs are untouched):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<!--  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" /> -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="****"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="SSL" />
    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" >
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: Obviously the problem is with your application, and the key to solving a problem is java.io.FileNotFoundException, which is not detailed in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple problems at once.

First as java.io.FileNotFoundException indicated, problem with war structure.

Second IDEA has its own tomcat server aside mine manually installed, that made real confusion.